# append text to aria-label name

Tags: jquery, html, wai-aria

I have two slick sliders on my site; one that displays News the other Events .
I have an accessibility error because of duplicate aria label on the line with ***div.slick track***; I need to append text to first slick slider ***div.slick-track*** ***aria-label***.
I have tried to update the slick.min.js file and I keep breaking the file. So I'm' just trying to write some jQuery code (with no luck) to append text to the aria label in the first slider.
I have looked through the suggested answered questions Stack Overflow recommended with no luck. 
Here is part of my HTML

```
    <div aria-label="news" class="slick slick-initialized slick-slider" 
role="toolbar">
    <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" style="display: block;">Previous</button>                 
        <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
            <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 3487px; transform: translate3d(-2219px, 0px, 0px);" role="listbox" aria-label="slick-list">
```

This is what I have tried using

jQuery

```
$(".slick-track[aria-label='slick-list']").append("news");
```

//AND

```
   $(".slick-track[aria-label='slick-list']").find(function(){
        $(this).append("news");
    });
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `$(".slick-track[aria-label='slick-list']").append("news");` works. But your div has a `transform3d` style property applied to it which causes the text to not be visible.

Comment: _"Here is part of my HTML"_ - you mean `aria-label="slick-list"` is static HTML ...? Then why not change it _there_, instead of relying on JavaScript (which especially regarding users with disabilities might not be a given?) And even if this is output in a server-side template in a loop or via multiple function calls, you should be able to modify that according, adding a little if condition or an extra parameter maybe ...?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
document.getElementById('DIV_ID').setAttribute('aria-label', 'YOURTITLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   var last  =$(".slick-track").attr("aria-label");
   $(".slick-track").attr("aria-label",last+"new");
```

Answer (score 0):

*Append text to first slick slider* ***div.slick-track aria-label***:

```js
$(".slick-track[aria-label='slick-list']:first").append("news");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div aria-label="news" class="slick slick-initialized slick-slider" 
role="toolbar">
    <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" style="display: block;">Previous</button>                 
    <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 3487px; transform: translate3d(-2219px, 0px, 0px);" role="listbox" aria-label="slick-list">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So my original code did work. The issue was the slick.min.js file was loading after my jQuery code (file) in the DOM. Once I changed the order it worked.